# Flutter ListView builder range error in TabView

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I have a `ListView.builder` inside a page that contains multiple tabs.

After a list item is removed (by swiping left or right), going to another tab and then going back to the first tab results in a range error.

Going to another page and coming back does not result in an error. Perhaps going to another page causes the builder to re-build again, and tab doesn't?

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug with `TabView`? Fully reproducible code below.

To reproduce the issue swipe an item to delete it, then go to second tab and then back to first tab.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'List Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<int> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: const TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.recycling_outlined)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var item = list[index];
                return Dismissible(
                  key: Key(item.toString()),
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    list.removeAt(index);
                  },
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.toString()),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            const Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
            const Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping the list.removeAt(index) with a setState

Comment: Hi, that didn't help. "A dismissed dismissible widget is still part of the tree" error as soon as I try to remove the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separating the `ListView` solves tree the issue. To save the state of list, I am using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`, you can use  others state-management  property.

```dart
body: TabBarView(
  children: [
    FirstChild(),
    const Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
    const Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
  ],
),
```

ListView

```dart
class FirstChild extends StatefulWidget {
  FirstChild({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstChild> createState() => _FirstChildState();
}

class _FirstChildState extends State<FirstChild>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  List<int> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      itemCount: list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var item = list[index];
        return Dismissible(
          key: Key(list[index].toString()),
          onDismissed: (direction) {
            setState(() {
              list.removeAt(index);
            });
          },
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(item.toString()),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! Are there any negative implications of using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin? Is it not going to cause a memory leak? Do I need to do something special to dispose of it?

Comment: Actually, in my actual solution I am using provider, not a local list. It work without "automatic keep alive", it was just a matter of moving it to a separate class and setting state. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use setState to update list and also remove List declaration from build method

```
  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<int> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: const TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.recycling_outlined)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var item = list[index];
                return Dismissible(
                  key: Key(item.toString()),
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    setState(() {
                      list.removeAt(index);
                    });
                  },
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.toString()),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            const Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
            const Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work still the same error.

Comment: Can you share the error message you are getting ??

Comment: As soon as the item is deleted, this error is thrown: "A dismissed Dimissible widget is still part of the tree. Make sure to implement the onDismissed handle and to immediately remove the Dismissible widget from the application once that handler has fired."